# How to add new images to fbi slideshow automatically

Tags: raspberrypi, slideshow

I currently have rclone syncing photos from my cloud drive down to a Raspberry Pi running a `fbi` slideshow, and I'm wondering if there is a good way to have it automatically pick up the new photos that get synced to the pi.

Current `fbi` script being run on boot:

```
#!/bin/bash
INTERVAL=5
fbi -noverbose -a -u -blend 1000 -t $INTERVAL /home/pi/pictures/*
```

Comment: Probably not, unless you've willing to kill and restart your script when a new picture arrivves